# Rails Koala gem - get user's country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, koala-gem

I'm using OmniAuth and the Koala gem to add Facebook Connect to my app and i'm trying to get the user's country.

So far I have:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user.oauth_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
```

`profile["location"]` gives me the id and name of the city.

I've tried: `graph.get_object(city_id)` which returns the city object, but I can't find any mention of the city's country in it.

I can also get the country name from the location string: `"Kfar Saba, Israel"` but that seems like a hack... Any official way to get what i'm looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the issue that the location data is not always complete for Place pages. I think you'll need to implement the location string parsing as a fallback if the `location.country` field of the Place page is empty. Be aware that the location string *may* also contain the `location.state`, which means that you'll have to use the last token after the split by comma.

Graph API returns no country for the named city:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=114269838585202&version=v2.0

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page#readfields for the Page object structure.